# Get a custom answer, an object for an HTTP Post request in a Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, httprequest

I call this WebApi endpoint:

```
public IActionResult MyEndPoint([FromBody] MyType myType)
{
    // I do some stuff

    var answer = new MyAnswer { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };

    return Ok(answer);
}
```

The call to call the endpoint is this:

```
public async Task<string> httpPost(string url, string content)
{
    var response = string.Empty;
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri(url),
            Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };

        HttpResponseMessage result = await client.SendAsync(request);
        if(result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            response = result.StatusCode.ToString(); //here
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

I'd like to have access MyAnswer object returned with the Ok() where the //here is. I put a breakpoint but nothing look like my object.

Comment: `result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I see my Guid in the answer perfect. But when I want to  Deserialize like this JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyAnswer>(res); There is no exception but the Guid is 0000-0000 ...  any idea ?

Comment: Are you using `await` on the result of `result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`?

Comment: If you are not using custom (de)serializer against `MyAnswer` then `await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyAnswer>()` would do the magic for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public async Task<MyAnswer> HttpPost(string url, string content)
    {
        var response = new MyAnswer();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri(url),
                Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(content), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };

            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.SendAsync(request);
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                response =  JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyAnswer>(responseString, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```